# The $P(X) = 0.7$ and $P(Y) = 0.6$. What is the probability of $X$ or $Y$ occurring?

Tags: probability

So let's say we have two independent events. The $P(X) = 0.7$ and $P(Y) = 0.6$. What is the probability of $X$ or $Y$ occurring? I know how to calculate an or probability but this question is confusing me.

Comment: May be you are confusing independent events with disjoint (mutually exckusive) ones ?

Answer (score 3):

Recall inclusion exclusion
$$P(X\cup Y) = P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$$
and recall something special about
$$P(X\cap Y)$$
from the fact that they are independent.
By the way, this problem is an "or" problem.

Comment: I'm trying that but I have idea what my numbers are. .7 + .6 gives me 1.3 and I have no idea what my overlap it. The answer is supposed to be 0.88 but I have no idea how to get to that answer.

Comment: @DavidRolfe I see. For future reference, include all your work in your post. Recall that $P(X\cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score -1):

Given that P(x) = 0.7
P(Y) = 0.6

Then P(X or Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X and Y)(If you assume independence for X and y)

= 0.7 + 0.6 - (0.7*0.6)
= 1.3 - 0.42

P(X or Y) = 0.88